# I have got a ListFragment with some options but ItemClick doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have tried a lot of solutions I found in this web but anyone of them works, I have got this code:

```
public class Cambiar_ciudad extends ListFragment {

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_cambiar_ciudad, container,
                false);

        String[] values = new String[] {"Barcelona", "Madrid", "Sevilla", "Valencia" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;





    }
    }
```

That's code shows me the `List` with `("Barcelona", "Madrid", "Sevilla", "Valencia")` And I would like that when I push one of them they send me to a new layout.

I did it in a not fragment and It works with this code:

```
    Ciudades = new String[]{"Badajoz","Barcelona", "Madrid", "Sevilla", "Valencia"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Ciudades);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            if (position == 0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Menu_Principal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 1) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Menu_Principal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 2) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Menu_Principal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 3) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Menu_Principal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 4) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Menu_Principal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

But in a ListFragment I do not know how to link the options with `Menu_Principal.class`

I hope any of you can solve it, thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a method in ListFragment `onListItemClick` you can override it and in implementation you can start Menu_Principal activity

Comment: @RajeshBatth but how I add it to my code for a few buttons? I do not know how to use `onListItemClick` in a listFragment, the times I tried it I had problems

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Context context = getActivity();
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 1) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 2) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 3) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 4) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have got this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_cambiar_ciudad, container,
            false);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Badajoz","Barcelona", "Madrid", "Sevilla", "Valencia" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Context context = getActivity();
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Menu_Principal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    }


}
}
```

But it give me some errors here:

`(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){`

ListView its on red

v its on red

And a few ";" expected

Error:(35, 36) error: ';' expected

Error:(35, 53) error: ';' expected

Error:(35, 54) error: not a statement

Error:(35, 55) error: ';' expected

Error:(35, 70) error:  expected

Error:(35, 76) error: not a statement

Error:(35, 78) error: ';' expected